# Is there a way to sum up the size of files listed?

Tags: shell-script, ksh, hp-ux

This is the command I am using to list some files:

```
find . -name \*.extract.sys -size +1000000c -exec ls -lrt {} \;
-rw-r--r--   1 qa1wrk15   test       1265190 Sep 29 01:14 ./var/can/projs/ar/rep/extract/Sep/29/ar.ARAB-PI_7.20110929.extract.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 qa1wrk15   test       1345554 Sep 29 01:14 ./var/can/projs/ar/rep/extract/Sep/29/ar.ARAB-PI_2.20110929.extract.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 qa1wrk15   test       1370532 Sep 29 01:14 ./var/can/projs/ar/rep/extract/Sep/29/ar.ARAB-PI_3.20110929.extract.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 qa1wrk15   test       1399854 Sep 29 01:14 ./var/can/projs/ar/rep/extract/Sep/29/ar.ARAB-PI_8.20110929.extract.sys
```

and so on.

Now I want to calculate the total size of these files by summing up the 5th column. I thought of using `awk`, to do this so I tested the following in a particular directory

```
>ls -lrt | awk `{ print $1 }`
ksh: syntax error at line 1 : `{' unmatched
```

I don't understand what is the problem, why this **syntax error**.

I am thinking to try

```
ls -lrt | awk `BEGIN {total = 0} {for(i=0;i<NR;i++){total+=$5}} END {printf "%d",total}
```

this also, but a simple `awk` script is not working.

Please suggest or correct me if I am wrong, or if there is a workaround for this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, you should use straight single quotes (`'`), not the inclined ones (`` ` ``).

The `awk` inline script could be as follow:

```
ls -lrt | awk '{ total += $5 }; END { print total }'
```

so, no need to initialize `total` (`awk` initializes it to zero), and no need to loop, `awk` already executes the script on every line of input.

Comment: In summary, the one-liner would be this:

`find . -name \*.extract.sys -size +1000000c -exec ls -lrt {} \; | awk '{ total += $5 }; END { print total }' `

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/22005)

Comment: @enzotib : there are some rows where third column is blank, so the sum of 5th column is not working right, is there anyway to accommodate those

Answer (score 16):

@enzotib has already pointed out what your syntax error is - I'm going to go off on a little tangent.

Summing a column of numbers is one of those things that keeps popping up. I've ended up with this shell function:

```
sumcol() 
{ 
    awk "{sum+=\$$1} END {print sum}"
}
```

With this, your solution becomes:

```
ls -lrt | sumcol 5
```

That will sum the numbers in column 5 and print the value.

Comment: In effect, I was wondering why there is not a standard utility for that.

Comment: Goes right into my `.aliases` file.

Answer (score 15):

Here is another way to do this by using `du`:

```
find . -name \*.extract.sys -size +1000000c -print0 | du -c --files0-from=- | awk 'END{print $1}'
```

Comment: Excellent use of du. Nice example. As an added benefit, you can add the "-h" option to du in order to get the output in Gig. Then you don't have to count digits and such. I just ran a test on a bunch of files that are approximately 1188800 kbytes in size. How big is that? No matter, `du -ch --files0-from=-` tells me that my total is "9.0G". Sweeeet!

Comment: Sweet, excellent use of du!

Comment: Also, if you are only interested in the total, then pipe du output to `tail -1`.

Answer (score 5):

In case HP-UX `find` also has `-printf` option, that would be useful to compose a formula for `bc` to calculate:

```
( find . -name \*.extract.sys -size +1000000c -printf '%s+'; echo 0 ) | bc
```

If the formula gets too big, it can be calculated step-by-step:

```
( find . -name \*.extract.sys -size +1000000c -printf 's+=%s\n'; echo s ) | bc
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `find`:

```
find -name '*.extract.sys' -size +1000000c -printf '%s\n' | jq -s add
```

With GNU `stat`:

```
find . -name '*.extract.sys' -size +1000000c -exec stat -c%s '{}' + | jq -s add
```

With BSD `stat`:

```
find . -name '*.extract.sys' -size +1000000c -exec stat -f%z '{}' + | jq -s add
```

Comment: Is `jq` a utility? Don't seem to find on debian distribution (Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux)