# sum all numbers from "du"

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, perl, disk-usage

We want to calculate the first numbers that we get from `du`

```
du -b /tmp/*
6       /tmp/216c6f99-6671-4865-b8bc-7205f5388752_resources
668669  /tmp/hadoop7887078727316788325.tmp
6       /tmp/hadoop-hdfs
42456   /tmp/hive
32786   /tmp/hsperfdata_hdfs
6       /tmp/hsperfdata_hive
32786   /tmp/hsperfdata_root
262244  /tmp/hsperfdata_yarn
```

so final sum will be

```
sum=6+668669+6+42456+32786+6+32786+262244


echo $sum
```

How we can do it by awk or perl one liners?

Comment: `du -bs /tmp` would get you the answer too

Comment: See [How can I quickly sum all numbers in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702564/how-can-i-quickly-sum-all-numbers-in-a-file)

Comment: See also [Is there a way to sum up the size of files listed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21678/is-there-a-way-to-sum-up-the-size-of-files-listed)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In AWK:

```bsh
{ sum += $1 }
END { print sum }
```

So

```bsh
du -b /tmp/* | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

Note that the result won’t be correct if the directories under `/tmp` have subdirectories themselves, because `du` produces running totals on directories and their children.

`du -s` will calculate the sum for you correctly (on all subdirectories and files in `/tmp`, including hidden ones):

```bsh
du -sb /tmp
```

and `du -c` will calculate the sum of the listed directories and files, correctly too:

```bsh
du -cb /tmp/*
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also produce a total sum of selected files with `du -c`. This works even if an argument of `du` is not a directory, what is not the case of `du -s`:

```
$ du -sb file1 file2
17  file1
18  file2

$ du -cb file1 file2
17  file1
18  file2
35  total
```

BTW, for interactive use I recommend adding `-h` option instead of `-b` or any other multiplier of block-size. This will print the size in human readable unit format.

```
$ du -ch file1 file2
4.0K    file1
4.0K    file2
8.0K    total
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple you can use:

```
 du -b /tmp/* | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} {i=i+$1} END{print i}'
```

If you are not using wildcard, if you are using directory name like `/tmp`, then you need to avoid the last entry because output of `du -b /tmp` is like:

```
size1 file1
size2 file2
size_total .
```

So now you should avoid this last entry, so use:

```
du -b /tmp | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} {if( $2 != "." ){i=i+$1}} END{print i}'
```

However you can also use `-s` option, it will calculate the summary for you then you don't need to add the values, just print the last one, i.e.:

```
du -s directory
```

Comment: variables initialize to zero, if you'd like to golf some bytes off :)